# How to integrate unit test for dotnet framework 4.8 project and run test using mstest using cli command

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, gitlab-ci

CLI command i tried,

```
VSTest.Console.exe <test-project-name>.dll
```

it shows error as

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.11.0
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in D:\office\TCSPL\MVC_WebApplication\MVC_WebApplication_test\obj\Release\MVC_WebApplication_test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Additionally, path to test adapters can be specified using /TestAdapterPath command. Example  /TestAdapterPath:.